# Why am I getting TypeError X is not a function

Tags: javascript, object, typeerror

I have an object with functions. When I call the function it is throwing a TypeError not a function. However the function looks correct.

The function throwing the type error is showSection. It is being called by showAddCreatureSection. hideSection, hideAddCreatureSection, hideEncounterLog functions are all working.

I have no idea why hideSection is throwing the typeError and looking for why

JavaScript

```
let informationArea = {
    informationArea: document.getElementById('tracker_additional_area'),
    addCreatureSection: document.getElementById('addCreatures'),
    encounterLogSection: document.getElementById('log'),

    hideSection: function(section_to_be_hidden){
        section_to_be_hidden.classList.add('hide');
    },

    showSection: function(section_to_be_shown){
        console.log('showSection');
        section_to_be_shown.classList.remove('hide');
    },

    hideAddCreatureSection: function(){
        this.hideSection(this.addCreatureSection);

        if(is_encounter_running === false || is_encounter_started === false){
            trackerButtons.add_creature_button.classList.remove('hide');
        }
    },

    showAddCreatureSection: function(){
        console.log('showAddCreatureSection');
        this.showSection(this.addCreatureSection);
    },

    hideEncounterLog: function(){
        this.hideSection(this.encounterLogSection);
    },

    showEncounterLog: function(){
        this.showSectionInInformationArea(this.encounterLogSection);
    },

    closeSection: function(exit_section_button){
        switch(exit_section_button.getAttribute('id')){
            case 'addCreatures':
                this.hideAddCreatureSection();
                break;
            case 'encounterLog':
                this.hideEncounterLog();
                break;
        }
    }
};
trackerButtons.add_creature_button.addEventListener('click',informationArea.showAddCreatureSection);
```

Comment: When you set up the event handler that way, the relationship between the object and the function is broken, so `this` won't have the correct value when the "click" happens.

Comment: Arrow functions ftw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that registering the `addEventListner()` function causes `this` to refer to the `window` object instead of the context you expect.

If it's possible to use ES6 arrow functions you might want to change your code to:

```
trackerButtons.add_creature_button.addEventListener('click', () => { informationArea.showAddCreatureSection });
```

if not, use:

```
trackerButtons.add_creature_button.addEventListener('click', function () { informationArea.showAddCreatureSection }.bind(this));
```

Comment: The arrow function didn't work but I made the callback function(){informationArea.showAddCreatureSection} and it works now